# How can I copy without getting different values?

Tags: excel, copy

So I marked two cells with `10.40` and `10.50` and now I want to copy those into other cells. But somehow Excel is adding 0.01 into those cells so I will get in the next two cells `10.41` and `10.51`. I'm just copying! No formula is in use.

Comment: Does that happen if you right click to paste, then paste as values? (the 123 symbol)?

Comment: Two heroes in one thread^^

Comment: I mark the two cells with shift and then drop the box until i got enough cells which I wanna fill with the data

Comment: Uhh so you're dragging down??

Comment: yes I dragged it down.

Answer (score 0):

When you paste, paste only the values. This is done by right clicking where you want to paste, and under then paste options select the the clipboard with 123 written on it.